# Allocating values in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Im very new to haskell and I have to define the elliptic curve functions from the RFC6090 Definition in Haskell. (RFC6090: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6090#section-3)
For that I have to implement a function called ecAdd.

ecAdd returns values from the type ECPoint. I defined them but Im not sure why the values x1 and x2 are not recognized. I get the following error for every section where x1,x2,y1 or y2 appears.

```
error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(Double -> Double) -> Fq -> Fq’
                  with actual type ‘galois-field-1.0.0:Data.Field.Galois.Prime.Prime
                                      Q’
    • The function ‘y2 - y1’ is applied to two arguments,
      but its type ‘galois-field-1.0.0:Data.Field.Galois.Prime.Prime Q’
      has none
      In the first argument of ‘(^)’, namely
        ‘((y2 - y1) recip (x2 - x1))’
      In the first argument of ‘(-)’, namely
        ‘((y2 - y1) recip (x2 - x1)) ^ 2’
   |        
64 |             x3 = ((y2 - y1) recip (x2 - x1))^2 - x1 - x2
```

Here is my function code

```
ecAdd
  :: ECPoint  -- ^ Punkt P
  -> ECPoint  -- ^ Punkt Q
  -> ECPoint  -- ^ Ergebnis P + Q


ecAdd q O = q
ecAdd O p = p
ecAdd (A x1 y1) (A x2 y2) =
  if (A x1 y1)  /=  (A x2 y2)
    then 
    if x1 == x2 
      then O
    else let x3 = ((y2-y1) recip (x2-x1))^2 - x1 - x2 
             y3 = (x1-x3)*(y2-y1) recip (x2-x1) - y1 in A x3 y3
  else 
    if y1 == 0 
      then O
    else let   x4 = ((3*x1^2 + P256K1._a) recip (2*y1))^2 - 2*x1
               y4 = (x1-x3)*(3*x1^2 + P256K1._a) recip (2*y1) - y1 
               in A x4 y4
```

Comment: I don't know the libraries you're using, but assuming `recip` is something to do with division and supposed to be used infix (ie between its two arguments, not before), you need to put backticks around it.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks Robin. Yes recip is dividing. But If I use suggested backticks like 'recip' then Im getting an syntax error on this.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks I solved the problem in a other way.